# How can I create a live USB with persistant storage that will run on a Macbook Air without using rEFIt?

Tags: grub2, macbook, uefi, refit

Sometimes I have to use a MacBook Air (2,1) at work. I'd like to be able to have an Ubuntu USB stick with persistent storage space for it, that does not require any modification of the machine's internal drive. So, that I can work in my normal (K)Ubuntu environment on the Machine and save stuff onto the stick. I don't want to install rEFIt or anything, since I am not to the only other of this machine. How can I achieve this?

I know that there is a Grub 2 version that supports EFI, which should do the trick in principle, but what are the necessary steps to get it working? Are there alternatives to this?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, the following answer seemed to help: [How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media)
There is a good chance that it will work fine for your Mac too.

Comment: While this might answer the question, link only answers are not a good fit for this site, because the link might become invalid. Please update your answer including a summary of the essential steps.

Answer (score -2):

1. just an "installation-stick" with your kubuntu .iso , boot it at work and the choose the live system - you can spare some space for files or programs to install, but booting will take about 5 minutes or so.
2. i haven't tried it - and its just an idea, but maybe if you take another PC and another stick and perform a simple clean install on the stick instead of the hdd (if this is possible) and then just plug it in at work and define it as the device to boot from, maybe it works. maybe.

just some random ideas, i'd be happy if they help you out!

Comment: That does not work. A Mac will only boot from a blessed USB drive with EFI Grub.

Comment: i thought about it. it should work if you are installing it from another USB drive onto a 2. one.
You would still need to tell your BIOS to boot from USB.

Comment: alright, 3 years old, still let me know if that worked ^^