# How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?

Tags: boot, live-usb, uefi

Having live media that can boot both ways can be a problem when installing Ubuntu onto currently available Windows 8 computers.

In other words the key advantage to creating **UEFI-only** bootable USB live media is: You know that it definitely booted and installed via UEFI.

<sub>Since Valve has already been doing UEFI-only booting USB installers with their *Debian-based* Steam OS and UNetbootin — the top voted alternative to Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator — isn't UEFI compatible and therefore misleading, I think we should have a separate topic for creating UEFI-only bootable USB live media.</sub>

Answer (score 153, accepted):

## Overview

Creating UEFI-only booting USB live media is pretty straight forward. Just copy the files to your *FAT32-formatted* USB drive. **That's it!**

Remember that for an installation or booting the media:

- You may still need to explicitly [tell your computer to boot the media via UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Set_up_the_BIOS_in_EFI_or_Legacy_mode).
- A [GPT partition table](https://askubuntu.com/q/509006/40581) like in preinstallations of Windows 8 and later is recommended.
- Don't forget to create a partition after you've created the partition table.
- Use the latest **AMD64** (LTS) ISOs, because these definitely contain UEFI bootloaders.

### Table of contents

- Copy files from the ISO method

  1. Example via terminal
  2. Example via GUI
  3. Example on Windows
- The ISO loopback method (advanced)

  1. Creating the binary
  2. Creating the configuration file
  3. Adding persistency
  4. Checking the integrity
  5. UEFI Secure Boot
- Review in 2020

---

## 1. Copy files from the ISO method

This method also works for other install media that contains EFI loaders, like Windows for example.

### 1.1. Example via terminal

You can do something like the following if `604A-00EA` is your USB drive and you already have `p7zip` installed:

```
$ 7z x ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso -o/media/$USER/604A-00EA/
```

You're done if you have only one partition on this USB drive, otherwise you need to flag the partition as bootable e.g. via `parted`:

```
# parted /dev/sdX set 1 boot on
```

Where `/dev/sdX` would be your USB drive and `1` the partition number that should be used to boot.

### 1.2. Example via GUI

1. Mount the .iso-file and copy the contents over to your USB drive. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in Nautilus to display and copy hidden files as well.

   [image: nautilus showing Disk Image Mounter in context menu when .iso-file is selected]
2. Add the boot flag via [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/).

   [image: GParted showing how to manage partition flags]

### 1.3. Example on Windows

1. Same as above, just copy files.
2. Press <kbd>Windows/Super</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, go to Disk Management and check if the partition is marked as active. On Windows versions prior to Windows 8, you press <kbd>Windows/Super</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the run menu and open `diskmgmt.msc`, that would open Disk Management.

## 2. The ISO loopback method (advanced)

Instead of extracting contents from an ISO image, GRUB and GRUB2 have been able to boot from ISO images directly through a loopback device. Given that the ISO image is UEFI bootable, we can set up a USB drive containing multiple ISOs with different operating systems without creating a mess on the USB drive.

<sub>If you want to boot Windows too you might want to look at [SARDU](https://superuser.com/q/267385/252532). I remember using it with Windows PE around 2005 and it seems to have been updated to support USB drives and UEFI, but remember that this tool also supports legacy booting.</sub>

What do we need?

- Very basic knowledge of GRUB configuration files.
- Very basic knowledge of UEFI booting and GRUB, as we are going to generate our own GRUB bootloader image with a plenty of modules included.
- A UEFI bootable ISO image, a FAT formatted USB drive and a machine that runs Linux.

  - No, we don't need a UEFI installation of Linux (which may be a chicken and egg situation), a traditional Linux VM like in VirtualBox is fine.

### 2.1. Creating the binary

On your Ubuntu machine or VM make sure the package [grub-efi-amd64-bin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/grub-efi-amd64-bin/) is installed (grub-efi-ia32-bin is also available for 32-bit Intel architectures on newer releases). The package may have a different name on another distribution, you can compare the [file listing of the package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/grub-efi-amd64-bin/filelist) to find the right package on your distribution.

The following command will generate the GRUB image, in this case an EFI binary that every computer with a UEFI firmware should be able to run:

```
grub-mkimage -o bootx64.efi -p /efi/boot -O x86_64-efi \
 fat iso9660 part_gpt part_msdos \
 normal boot linux configfile loopback chain \
 efifwsetup efi_gop efi_uga \
 ls search search_label search_fs_uuid search_fs_file \
 gfxterm gfxterm_background gfxterm_menu test all_video loadenv \
 exfat ext2 ntfs btrfs hfsplus udf
```

Every *standard* UEFI firmware should look into `\EFI\BOOT\` for a file named `boot{arch}.efi`, so create the folders on the USB drive and copy the image we just created to this location. Other architectures instead of x64 are possible, but let's keep it simple with x64/amd64.

### 2.2. Creating the configuration file

A very basic example for a the `grub.cfg` configuration file that should be placed in the same directory as `bootx64.efi` would look like this:

```
set timeout=3
set color_highlight=black/light-magenta

menuentry 'Boot Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS from ISO' {
        set isofile="/efi/boot/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject quiet splash persistent --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
submenu 'Useful snippets' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu' {
            chainloader /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
    }
    menuentry 'Windows' {
            chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    }
    menuentry 'Firmware Setup' {
            fwsetup
    }
}
```

The important thing is the configuration block with the title `Boot Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS from ISO`. You can change the color and timeout to your preference. I chose `black/light-magenta` as it still looks a bit Ubuntu-ish but is easily distinguishable when chainloading other configurations. You can find more examples for other distributions in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive) and reading the [GRUB manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Configuration) is really worth your time if you want to go beyond that.

Getting back to the configuration block, it should be obvious that the ISO is referenced as `/efi/boot/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`, so copy your ISO to `\EFI\BOOT\` and replace `ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` in the configuration with the actual filename of your ISO.

`loopback loop $isofile` is the line, that will load our ISO file to a loopback device from which we can boot the Linux kernel directly. This is possible because our EFI GRUB image includes the loopback module. (A bit of trial and error was involved in figuring out which modules are reasonable to include. You shouldn't see any error messages, it's still not perfect though.) Speaking of the kernel you can add kernel parameters like `toram`, parameters for different languages (example `locale=de_DE bootkbd=de`) and as in the example: `persistent`

### 2.3. Adding persistency

You can add a partition as described in: [How do I get a live-USB to use a partition for persistence?](https://askubuntu.com/q/138356/40581) Or you can create a `casper-rw` file and place it at the root of your USB drive.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=casper-rw bs=1M count=4094
mkfs.ext4 -m 0 casper-rw
```

I haven't tested what the absolute maximum is, it should be somewhere between 4094 and 4096 MB. Use a partition if you intend to use more space. Note that every change to the (root) is a modification to the overlay filesystem, even deleting files.

### 2.4. Checking the integrity

You should look at answers to the following questions to verify that the Live ISO content on the USB drive is in pristine condition:

- [How can I check the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/17764/40581)
- [Can an integrity check be run against a USB boot disk?](https://askubuntu.com/q/547332/40581)

### 2.5. UEFI Secure Boot

Secure Boot will become mandatory with Windows 10 machines, I suggest you have a look at the Linux Foundation's PreLoader to add Secure Boot functionality to this setup. Here is some [ASCII art illustrating menus of the accompanying HashTool](https://askubuntu.com/q/594747/40581).

## 3. Review in 2020

I wrote this answer more than 5 years ago. How well does it still work? It works well for Ubuntu. install.wim from latest Windows 10 images however exceeds the FAT32 maximum file size and bigger images like RHEL 8 also don't fit. I tried Rufus yesterday and noticed that it uses GRUB too with NTFS EFI modules to read another NTFS partition where it stored the Windows installation files. It failed to load data from this partition though. Also exFAT is now commonplace.

Windows is picky with drives that have no partition tables. Trying to re-purpose older SSDs as chunky USB thumb drives does not work really well on Windows. Maybe I need to read some Microsoft documentation to find out what the rationale was to make it a bit more complicated than on Linux.

ChromeOS is a different topic, I think it's not possible to create recovery media the way I prefer. Which is cumbersome when you have to use Windows and reformat the entire drive to create media for your Chromebook.

Interesting stuff, let's hope I find time to fix some of this and learn a few more new things.

---

Congratulations, I'd say you now mastered UEFI booting and shouldn't be afraid anymore.

Comment: let me point out (a) that all PCs shipped in the last 5 years or so have this capability; (b) that the .iso installer root then can use the full usb stick as ordinary persistent storage.  (use ro mount options to protect from accidental deletion.)  for modern PCs and common usage patterns, this seems like a better solution than live-usb-creator's default solution.

Comment: While using GUI method I have run into some [symbolic links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599516/symbolic-links-error-while-creating-ubuntu-uefi-bootable-usb) errors. Is this relevant? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hi, LiveWireBT! Thank you for such interesting answer!! I followed 2. The ISO loopback method (advanced) and managed to UEFI boot from usb flash drive. But, in the end of booting I got the error message:  **Can not mount /dev/loop2 on /cow** and after pressing enter I saw a (initramfs) prompt. Can you help me with it?

Comment: I want to also thank you for a great guide, it was clear and concise. I never even thought of partitioning the thumb drive and having multiple OS's on it. Thanks again!

Comment: In 16.04 at least, the "copy all files" fails to boot because of the grub.cfg kernel line argument "file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed".  There is no such file, probably related to previously mentioned missing symbolic link (ubuntu to .).  Edit the grub.cfg to remove the file=... and replace it with "live-media-path=/casper/   ignore_uuid"

Comment: Some files are too large to be copied to a fat32 fs.

Comment: > Just copy the files to your FAT32-formatted USB drive

Concerning the USB drive formatting… As a Mac OS user I have to ask: when I'm using Disk Utility to format ("Erase") USB flash drive, what should I choose in the "Scheme"? Available options are the following:
- GUID Partition map
- Master Boot Record
- Apple Partition map

Comment: Re section 1.1: have you tried to create different partitions in the USB drive, each with the image of a different Ubuntu release, for installing the specific release whose partition is made bootable for the occasion? In the meantime I have asked also at https://askubuntu.com/q/1216314/446253

Comment: @LiveWireBT You need to add details to the Terminal instructions. What partitioning scheme does the USB need to use? If it's GPT, then does the FAT32 partition need to be designated an EFI system partition? Do the files need to be extracted into the root of the FAT32 partition or to a folder named `EFI`, as in almost all ESP setups? What if the ISO has more than one partition? If we're using UEFI, then why are we setting a boot flag?

Comment: Sorry that I have not answered to the latest two comments. I have currently not much time for further investigation for some of the statements made. @Melab Do you have an example for an ISO with multiple partitions? Setting the boot flag in gparted should configure the partition to be bootable (MBR) or an ESP (GPT).

Comment: Incredible, the 7z method worked. Some image done with dd created a USB that was simply completely ignored by this Mac from 2011. Did not even need to run the 'parted' thing. Did format the USB fat32 (rather than) before doing the 7z maybe that had something to do with it.

Comment: The ISO loopback method begins the booting, but it simply stops after mounting the .iso file (Fedora 38, 2023).

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Please check out Ventoy, I have been using it for some time now and although it formats your storage in a particular way I found it easy to use with low maintenance and a lot of features. I store Fedora, Ubuntu, Windows and a few more ISOs on my Ventoy drives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I need by Live drive as a partition (for emergencies), while the second partition is where I have my main pen drive. Does Ventoy allow this?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit No it doesn't. Just get a micro SD card and a small reader sized like a thumb drive or get another USB drive and stop worrying about it. Storage has become ever more inexpensive, I can get a micro SD card where I can store all the images and more I listed above already and I have a few of those Ventoy formatted drives, so I never have to spend time searching for that one special drive with all the images.

Comment: I guess our objectives are different. I only want one linux live with me all the time, with the sole purpose of recovering a system or do maintance, anywhere and with everyone that needs it. I already carry all my important stuff in a cryptographed pen-drive, and I don't want to carry two. I already have this: essentially your 'dd method', but wanted to implement the loopback method since it is easier to keep it updated. Nothing to do with money, but with convenience. Yet, it was very interesting to know about Ventoy, thanks.

Comment: I tried using option 2 - in Nautilus onto my FAT32 USB drive, and get the error `Error while copying "stable". Filesystem does not support symbolic links.` What to do please?

Answer (score 5):

### Extract from ISO file to FAT32

Extracting the content of an Ubuntu 64-bit desktop ISO file to a partition with a FAT32 file system and a boot flag will do the job: to create a live drive, that boots only in UEFI mode. It is called 'Copy files from the ISO method' here (in the accepted answer).

### Test if running in UEFI or BIOS mode

But it is easy to test in a running Ubuntu system (live as well as installed), if it was booted in UEFI or BIOS mode. Run this command line,

```
test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios
```

This makes it straightforward to use live systems that can be used in both boot modes, which can also be an advantage.

See also the following links for a more detailed explanation and description of the method,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy)

Comment: Easiest method. The latest iso still won't boot EFI (on my machines) unless media is formatted gpt.
The /cdrom directory speaks of an earlier time. Maybe time to update the install framework.

Answer (score 3):

Using `dd` worked for me, for some reason, the GUI version did not work. So, first, you might want to [monitor the progess of dd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220652/is-dd-taking-too-long), another options is using the SIGUSR1 option to trigger `dd` to report it's progress periodically, but this is more complicated than `pv`.

Then:

```
sudo dd if=path/to/image/file | pv | sudo dd of=/dev/device_you_want_to_use
```

(`/dev/device_you_want_to_use` will typically be `/dev/sdb`, but check with `df`!)

Comment: Creating media this way does not result in UEFI-**only** bootable media. Emphasis is on the last paragraph of the question: *"There is also one advantage to creating UEFI-only booting USB live media: You know that it definitely booted via UEFI."* Having media that can boot both ways is a problem when trying to understand and setup a UEFI-bootable Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I see. The weird thing is that this way, I was able to produce a image that booted in UEFI mode (I know that, since the laptop was set to allow only uefi boot and also because of the inital screen). The preffered answer did not work for me, the computer would just not boot with an image created by just copying the files.

Comment: @sup this method creates media that *can* be UEFI-booted. The problem is that it's not *only* UEFI-bootable, as requested in the question: it can also be booted in BIOS mode.

Comment: everyone forgets that you can use status=progress to view progress